# How can I connect SSIS to SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have to Virtual Machines, one with Windows XP and the other with Windows Server 2008. In my XP VM I have SQL Server 2000 with a database that is my datasource. In WS 2008 I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with an SSIS package to pull data from SQL Server 2000.

My problem: I can not connect to SQL Server 2000, I can not create a connection in my SSIS package. The error says "The connection faild because of an error in initializing provider. Login file for user sa" I am using sa user for the connection and of course this user has access to the database.

Things I have done:

-Both VM do ping between each other.

-I am using Native OLE DB\ Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

-Did this configuration from this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx

I continue with the problem, I need to use Sql Server Authentication. Please if any one has another suggestion, please help.

Regards, Anabel

Comment: Do you have login audit on SQL Server enabled? If so, whats the error from there.

Comment: This is what I find in SQL logs: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.100.3] but of course the pass is well writen, I tested serveral times. Any ideas??

Comment: Can you check the package security protection level, under the SSIS package property tab. What is it set to? It should be `DontSaveSensitive`

Comment: I changed it, it didn´t work, I´m creating a new data source, not yet related to a package anyway. Any other ideas? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had no problems to connect to SQL 2000 from SQL 2008 R2 is perfectly posible. My problem was a configuration problem between my two virtual machines. I tried to do the connection in a normal enviroment and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to all for the comments.

Anabel